# Building Darknet but getting this errors

Tags: darknet

```
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler - NOTFOUND
-- CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6
-- CUDACXX: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6/bin/nvcc
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (message):
  CUDA not found, please build explicitly with -DENABLE_CUDA=OFF if you do
  not want CUDA.
```

I have Cuda 11.6 and cudnn 8.3

Comment: Are you really sure that darknet supports such a new CUDA version?

Comment: Should I use older version ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CUDA version 11.1. Worked for me.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help
I m trying to use the output from darknet to do further processing 
Can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure. Please share the details

Comment: I tried to use opencv dnn with yolov4 but i m getting low fps ie. 4 to 5fps
but while using darknet directly i mgetting 30 fps